# Получаю ошибку "Cannot GET /"

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Получаю ошибку, когда пытаюсь открыть мою страницу.

Код:

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(___dirname, '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Опишите ошибку которая возникает

Comment: При открытие сайта, возникает ошибка "Cannot GET /", исходный код прилагается выше.

Comment: @AndrewRogachuk ввиду тематики сайта, хоть большинство участников и знают английский, вопрос должен задаваться на русском языке. Пожалуйста переведите заголовок Вашего вопроса и текст в вопросе. Для этого воспользуйтесь ссылкой **править**, расположенной под метками вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо этого

```
res.sendfile(___dirname, '/index.html');
```

напишите это

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
```

Comment: или ещё проще res.sendfile("./index.html");